# Understanding `const getLayout = Component.getLayout || (page => page)`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

I'm reading through [this](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/) article and I started to get lost in the syntax at "Option 3"

The code is this:

```
// /pages/account-settings/basic-information.js
import AccountSettingsLayout from '../../components/AccountSettingsLayout'

const AccountSettingsBasicInformation = () => <div>{/* ... */}</div>

AccountSettingsBasicInformation.layout = AccountSettingsLayout

export default AccountSettingsBasicInformation

// /pages/_app_.js
import React from 'react'
import App from 'next/app'

class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props
    const Layout = Component.layout || (children => <>{children}</>)

    return (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps}></Component>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

The part I'm having a hard time understanding is `const Layout = Component.layout || (children => <>{children}</>)`. I know that `||` means or so it's going to execute both parts but then I don't know what `Layout` would be assigned.

Then in "Option 4" it gets a little more confusing with the line `const getLayout = Component.getLayout || (page => page)`

I know that `page => {/*something here*/}` is a function but `(page => page)` doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a typo in that option 3, it should be `({ children }) => <>{children}</>` since it is declaring an anonymous component and rendering the `children` prop.

```
const Layout = Component.layout || (({ children }) => <>{children}</>);
```

What is going on here is the logical OR (`||`) is providing a fallback value to assign to `Layout` which treated as a React component later in the JSX:

```
return (
  <Layout>
    <Component {...pageProps}></Component>
  </Layout>
);
```

It will only evaluate the second half if the first half of the boolean expression evaluates to false, i.e. it continues to process the expression to find any part that is truthy. Javascript uses short-circuiting logic in boolean expressions, i.e. in a series of logical OR's as soon as a truthy value is found it skips the rest of the expressions. Similarly with a series of logical AND (`&&`) as soon as a falsey value is found the rest is skipped and false is returned.

With the option 4 the the `getLayout` is a function that takes a JSX literal and returns it. The fallback is just the simplest version of this function, consuming a `page` JSX literal and returning it without any additional layout wrappers/styling/etc..

```
// set the function
const getLayout = Component.getLayout || (page => page); 

// invoke function and render return value
return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps}></Component>);
```

Comment: I made a follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67855495/designing-persistent-layouts-in-next-js) to understand implementation of the strategy a bit better... Would love your feedback!

Comment: @financial_physician Taking a look now.