# Designing persistent layouts in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm going through [this](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/) article and I'm trying to figure out how the persistence is supposed to occur in Option 4. From what I can tell, you'd need to redefine the .getLayout for every page. I'm not sure how the logic for nesting is incorporated into further urls.

Here's the code from the article

```
// /pages/account-settings/basic-information.js
import SiteLayout from '../../components/SiteLayout'
import AccountSettingsLayout from '../../components/AccountSettingsLayout'

const AccountSettingsBasicInformation = () => <div>{/* ... */}</div>

AccountSettingsBasicInformation.getLayout = page => (
  <SiteLayout>
    <AccountSettingsLayout>{page}</AccountSettingsLayout>
  </SiteLayout>
)

export default AccountSettingsBasicInformation

// /pages/_app.js
import React from 'react'
import App from 'next/app'

class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, router } = this.props

    const getLayout = Component.getLayout || (page => page)

    return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps}></Component>)
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

For example, say `AccountSettingsBasicInformation.getLayout` is `/settings/`, how would I use this template to produce something at `/settings/username`

---

P.S. If someone has done something in the past they'd recommend over this, I'm open to ideas.

Comment: The `children` of a component are passed as a prop. Personally, I would create a Layout and then use `{props.children}` to render the content of `username` inside of the layout. That way, when you render `/settings/username`, you can just import the layout and wrap the content of `username` in the layout JSX component.

Comment: Also, I believe you have to wrap the `page` in a fragment: `const Layout = Component.layout || (children => <>{children}</>)` or `const getLayout = Component.getLayout || (page => <>{page}</>)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to redefine the `getLayout` function to every page. As long as the `SiteLayout` component stays “unchanged” (eg.no props change) the rendered content in that layout component (not the page content itself) stays persistent. This is because React wont rerender that component.

I used Adam’s article when I was building next.js lib for handlin modal routes. You can check the example folder where you can see I am defining the `getLayout` property on every page which should be rendered with layout.

Example: https://github.com/svobik7/next-bodies/tree/master/example